# How to loop through custom posts in admin edit screen

Tags: custom-post-types

How can I access the loop that displays all the custom posts in a custom post type's `edit.php` page? Is there some sort of hook for this?

I want to do some condition checking on the data that is being pulled during the loop and it doesn't seem like WP offers any obvious solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom posts"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is some sort of hook for this: [manage_posts_custom_column](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column)

Pseudo code:

```
function my_cpt_custom_column( $column ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'my_cpt' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        switch ( $column ) {
            case 'title':
                // do stuff with $post->post_title
                echo $post->post_title;
                break;
            case 'some-other-heading':
                // do stuff
                break;
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'my_cpt_custom_column' );
```

Comment: Use this for custom post types. 'manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column'